# can't disable my UFW

Tags: ufw

i want to setup a server in my local network and i want to disable my ufw.
After i have checked the web i have seen that i need to run the command: "sudo ufw disable".

after i have used the command my terminal responds: "firewall stopped and disabled on system startup". 
afterwards i restart my machine and after run the command: "systemctl status ufw".

when i run the given command it says that my ufw is "active (exited)".
it seems that my firewall is still blocking my activities.

how can i completely disable my firewall then? please help.
BTW i have seen ways to delete all the rules on the firewall, but i don't want that, i want a way that i can simply turn on/off my firewall whenever i need.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`systemctl` and `ufw` are telling you different things.

When the systemd *service* named `ufw` is enabled, then `systemd` will start the service at boot time. If we look at what that means:

```
$ cat /lib/systemd/system/ufw.service
[Unit]
Description=Uncomplicated firewall
Documentation=man:ufw(8)
DefaultDependencies=no
Before=network.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/lib/ufw/ufw-init start quiet
ExecStop=/lib/ufw/ufw-init stop

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

we can see that it executes `/lib/ufw/ufw-init start quiet`. In turn, if we look there, we see:

```
# Debian/Ubuntu: small boot speed improvement
. "${rootdir}/etc/ufw/ufw.conf"
if [ "$1" = "start" ] && [ "$2" = "quiet" ] && [ "$ENABLED" = "no" ]; then
    exit 0
fi
```

i.e. it sources `${rootdir}/etc/ufw/ufw.conf` and checks the value of `ENABLED`. Finally, if you check `/etc/ufw/ufw.conf` you will see a section like

```
# Set to yes to start on boot. If setting this remotely, be sure to add a rule
# to allow your remote connection before starting ufw. Eg: 'ufw allow 22/tcp'
ENABLED=yes
```

where `ENABLED=yes` toggles to `ENABLED=no` when you execute `sudo ufw disable`.

tl;dr the UFW **service** is enabled, but if UFW itself is disabled, none of its rules will be loaded.

Comment: when i checked the ufw.conf it is on ENABLED=no.
this means it is disabled?
so why i get https blocks, yet when i add rules to allow these ports it works?

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to turn off the firewall as it is built into the kernel. You can stop iptables which will given exception to firewall rules.

> sudo service iptables stop

**Edited content based on comment:**

In some cases if iptables has been replaced by firewalld, then we can use the below command to disable firewall. Try the below details.

> systemctl stop firewalld
>
> systemctl disable firewalld
>
> rm '/etc/systemd/system/dbus-org.fedoraproject.FirewallD1.service'
>
> rm '/etc/systemd/system/basic.target.wants/firewalld.service

Comment: it says:
Failed to stop iptable.service: unit iptable.service not loaded

Comment: Neither Debian nor Ubuntu run iptables as a service. rpm systems used to run iptables as a service before firewalld